# What's wrong with my taillight verilog design?

Tags: verilog, state-machines

I'm working on a T-bird car taillight design code, here is my design:
B means brake, all lights on at break,
when turn left lights on sequence:  000000 -> 001000 ->011000->111000
     turn right lights on sequence: 000000 -> 000001 ->000011->000111

[image]

```
 module taillight (clka, clkb, restart,brake,right,left,lc,lb,la, ra,rb,rc,state);
    input   clka, clkb, restart,brake,right,left;
    output  lc,lb,la, ra,rb,rc;
    output[2:0] state;
    wire    clka, clkb, restart,brake,right,left;
    reg     lc,lb,la, ra,rb,rc;
    parameter SIZE = 3;
    parameter IDLE  = 3'b000, l1 = 3'b001, l2 = 3'b011,  l3 = 3'b010,
              B  = 3'b100,    r1 = 3'b101, r2 = 3'b111,  r3 = 3'b110;
    //internal variable
    reg   [SIZE-1:0]          state        ;// Seq part of the FSM
    wire  [SIZE-1:0]          c_state   ;// Internal state reg
    reg   [SIZE-1:0]          n_state   ;// combo part of FSM

    assign c_state = fsm_function(state,brake,right,left,restart);
    //----------Function for Combo Logic-----------------
    function [SIZE-1:0] fsm_function;
      input  [SIZE-1:0] state,brake,right,left,restart;
    case(state)
       IDLE: begin
               if (!restart&&!brake&&!right&&!left) begin
                 fsm_function = IDLE;
               end else if(!restart&&!brake&&!right&&left) begin
                 fsm_function = l1;
               end else if(!restart&&!brake&&right&&!left) begin
                 fsm_function = r1;
               end else if(!restart&&(brake||(right&&left))) begin
                 fsm_function = B;
               end
             end
       l1: begin
               if (!brake) begin
                 fsm_function = l2;
               end else begin
                 fsm_function = B;
               end
             end
       l2: begin
              if (!brake) begin
                 fsm_function = l3;
               end else begin
                 fsm_function = B;
               end
             end
       l3: begin
                if (!brake) begin
                 fsm_function = IDLE;
               end else begin
                 fsm_function = B;
               end
             end
       r1: begin
              if (!brake) begin
                 fsm_function = r2;
               end else begin
                 fsm_function = B;
               end
             end
       r2: begin
              if (!brake) begin
                 fsm_function = r3;
               end else begin
                 fsm_function = B;
               end
             end
       r3: begin
              if (!brake) begin
                 fsm_function = IDLE;
               end else begin
                 fsm_function = B;
               end
             end
        B: begin
               fsm_function = IDLE;
             end
      default : fsm_function = IDLE;
      endcase
    endfunction

    //----------Seq Logic-----------------------------
    always @ (posedge clka)
    begin : FSM_SEQ                
      if (restart == 1'b1) begin
        n_state <= IDLE;
      end else begin
        n_state <= c_state;
      end
    end

    //----------Output Logic——————————————
    always @ (posedge clkb)
    begin : OUTPUT_LOGIC
      case(n_state)
      IDLE: begin
              state <= n_state;
              {lc,lb,la,ra,rb,rc} <= 6'b000000;
            end
      l1: begin
              state <= n_state;
              {lc,lb,la,ra,rb,rc} <= 6'b001000;
            end
      l2: begin
              state <= n_state;
              {lc,lb,la,ra,rb,rc} <= 6'b011000;
              end
      l3: begin
              state <= n_state;
              {lc,lb,la,ra,rb,rc} <= 6'b111000;
             end
      r1: begin
              state <= n_state;
              {lc,lb,la,ra,rb,rc} <= 6'b000001;
             end
      r2: begin
              state <= n_state;
              {lc,lb,la,ra,rb,rc} <= 6'b000011;
            end
      r3: begin
              state <= n_state;
              {lc,lb,la,ra,rb,rc} <= 6'b000111;
             end
      B: begin
              state <= n_state;
              {lc,lb,la,ra,rb,rc} <= 6'b111111;
             end
       endcase
    end // End Of Block OUTPUT_LOGIC

    endmodule // End of Module twoP_FSM
```

my testbench is like:

```
module taillight_tb();

reg in_clka, in_clkb, in_restart,in_brake,in_right,in_left;
wire out_lc,out_lb,out_la, out_ra,out_rb,out_rc;
wire [2:0] out_state;
integer i;
parameter [5:0] value = 6'b000000;
//create an FSM instance.
taillight U1 (.clka (in_clka),
           .clkb (in_clkb),
           .restart (in_restart),
           .brake (in_brake),
           .right (in_right),
           .left  (in_left),
           .lc  (out_lc),
           .lb  (out_lb),
           .la  (out_la),
           .rc  (out_rc),
           .rb  (out_rb),
           .ra  (out_ra),
           .state (out_state)
             );

initial
begin

  for(i=0;i<64;i=i+1)
    begin
      {in_clka, in_clkb, in_restart,in_brake,in_right,in_left}=value+i;
      #1;
    end

$dumpfile ("taillight_tb.vcd");
$dumpvars;
$display ("in_clka,\t in_clkb,\t in_restart,\t in_brake, \t in_right, \t in_left \t out_lc, \t out_lb, \t out$

$stop;
end

endmodule
```

But when I test my code on moldesim, the waveform looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state` is only being updated on the rising edge of `clkb`, where it takes the value of `n_state`, and `n_state` is only updated at the rising edge of `clka`, where it takes the value of `c_state`. The only thing that matters is the state of the other inputs when `clka` rises, but you have the clock lines as the two slowest lines, so there's a whole lot of not much happening.

If you reverse the order of bits in the for loop, you'll at least have a lot more going on.

You generally want the clocks to be the highest frequency signals.

There are a few other issues you might have. You generally need to make sure that input signals have a minimum setup and hold time around the clock edge. If you have asynchronous signals coming in, you can just run the signal through a few flip flops to mitigate any resulting instability. Similarly, people tend to run chips off of a single clock. If you can't guarantee the timing between the two clocks, you can run into the same setup and hold time violations, which will make your design very unstable.